# Disable JavaScript embedded in PDF in browser (XSS attack)

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4, javascript-injection

We are trying to load a PDF in an iframe using ExtJs. The PDF is embedded with JavaScript. When it is loaded in the browser, the alert is being displayed and it is considered as JS injection in penetration testing.

Any help to avoid the JS execution from PDF?

**Edit 1**

Tried using **sandbox**, **html embed element**.

sandbox doesn't display whole PDF when viewed in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Below is the code

```
onResearchGridPanelDBItemClick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        var pdf = record.get('path');
        var title = Encoder.htmlDecode(record.get('title'));
        var pdfPanel = null;
        var pdfTab = null;
        var p = Ext.getCmp('ResearchPanel');
        if(p){
            pdfPanel = p;   
        }else{
            pdfPanel = Ext.create('sample',{
                modal: true,        
                border:false,
                resizable: false
            });
        }
        console.log("RESEARCHCLICK: "+pdf+" launched by "+username);
        pdfPanel.show();
        if(pdfPanel.getEl()){
            pdfPanel.body.update('<b>'+title+'</b>'+ '<br><br>' + '<iframe style="height: 100%; width:100%; border: none" src="'+contextPath+'/resources/research/'+pdf+'"></iframe>');
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use `embed` instead of `iframe` like:

```
onResearchGridPanelDBItemClick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        var pdf = record.get('path');
        var title = Encoder.htmlDecode(record.get('title'));
        var pdfPanel = null;
        var pdfTab = null;
        var p = Ext.getCmp('ResearchPanel');
        if(p){
            pdfPanel = p;   
        }else{
            pdfPanel = Ext.create('sample',{
                modal: true,        
                border:false,
                resizable: false
            });
        }
        console.log("RESEARCHCLICK: "+pdf+" launched by "+username);
        pdfPanel.show();
        if(pdfPanel.getEl()){
            pdfPanel.body.update('<b>'+title+'</b>'+ '<br><br>' + '<embed type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%" src="'+contextPath+'/resources/research/'+pdf+'">');
        }
    },
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the answer is not working. the problem is with pdf. it has javascript embedded. so when we open the file even in pdf viewer, script is being executed